# Swift 3: Need to pass data to next view controller without moving to it

Tags: swift, segue, alamofire

I need to pass data from one viewcontroller, data from Alamofire request, and must be send to UIlabels in next View Controller. I do not want to transition to that View Controller yet. But the destination View Controller must be able to read and use the data from the Alamofire request. I tried it with a segue, but I do not get it working and Im doubting if this is the correct way to do it.

This is what I have:

```
Alamofire.request(URL_SCAN_ID, method: .post, parameters: ScanParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default) .responseJSON
                {

                    response in

                    //printing response
                    print(response.request!)
                    print(response.response!)
                    print(response.data!)
                    print(response.result)
                    print(response.error)

                    //getting the json value from the server
                    let value = response.result.value
                    print(value!)
                    let json = JSON(value!)

                    let productdesc0:JSON = json["productdesc"]
                    let productdescString = productdesc0.string



                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ScanInfo", sender: productdescString)


                   func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any){
                    if (segue.identifier == "ScanInfo"){
                        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ScanInfoViewController
                        destinationVC.productdescription01 = productdescString!
                        print("oeiii",sender)
                    }


            }
```

I think the data is not even send to the segue...the print is not showing anything.

Comment: Yep, not the correct way of doing things. First, don't call your network methods from a view controller. Second, performSegue should initiate the transition you don't want. Third, prepareForSegue should be in the ViewController, and should have to be marked with "override". If you set a breakpoint in that method, I assume it's not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code prepare function is inside the closure. It has to be on file level. If given code is from a view controller, it has to be like -

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ScanInfo"){
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ScanInfoViewController
        destinationVC.productdescription01 = productdescString!
        print("oeiii",sender)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that aswell, problem is then that I can not use productdescString, because it is used inside a function

Comment: Then you have to record it. Use a class property. Having prepare function inside some other scope is not going to work. It has to be available on class level and has to be overridden.

Comment: I adjusted it, I made a small adjustment:

Comment: Made a string variable in the view controller, used that one in the Alamofire request. It seems like the data is not immediately loaded when I come the destination view controller. Any idea?

Comment: Hi Avi, just read you're message. I have to figure out how to do that (working with a class property) but I think aswell segue is not working in this case. If you have an example somewhere would be nice :) Anyway thanks!